# iOS - Navigation bar color transition when pressing back button

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar, transition

I'm trying to change the color of the navigation bar when pushing a view controller on the navigation stack, using barTintColor during navigationController(_:willShow:animated:).

Here is the code:

```
  func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewController is ViewerViewController {
      navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(custom: .white)
      navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(custom: .black)
    } else if viewController is FeedViewController {
      navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(custom: .blue)
      navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(custom: .white)
    }
  }
```

Everything works beautifully when I push the view controller and when I use the swipe back gesture (color transition is smooth in both ways).

**However when I press the back button**, color doesn't change at first, the navigation transition is done, and then **color is changed with no animation**.

Did anyone already encountered / resolved this issue ? Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: if you write the code then it will be easy for us to determine why it's happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [KMNavigationBarTransition library](https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition) which works very well and doesn't require a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, so replaced the "back" button with a custom left bar button, and called:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

edit:

setting the leftBarButton was causing the loss of the swipe gesture, so I needed another hack:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pop))
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

Comment: This unfortunately loses the swipeToGoBack gesture of navigation controller :(

Comment: @OliverAtkinson adding the interactivePopGestureRecognizer delegate solves this issue

Comment: Thanks, and what does the implementation look like for that delegate gesture look like?

Comment: @Oliver Atkinson it can be an empty implementation